# Trying to get a flow to create a new record in related object but only option is $Record

Tags: visual-workflow, create-records, relatedrecord

I'm learning to create a more complex flow, at least for me, and I'm stuck. I've been searching, but I might be missing the right keywords, so hopefully you can help me.

I have those two objects: `Session` and `Seances`.
I want the flow to create multiple records of Seances related to a Session.
The two are linked with a master-detail relationship.

Rookie me does not understand why `$Record` is my only option to create a new record, instead of having the choice with all the other objects, since I'm after `Seances`.

[image]

**If you can explain that to me and point me towards the right direction, THANK YOU**

Comment: Create a flow resource variable to hold the (collection of) record(s) you want to create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a record, you must first have a Variable for that record. To create multiple records, you further need a Collection Variable to hold the list of records to create.

First, open the toolbox using the leftmost button on the top toolbar. It looks like a square with a smaller rectangle on the left. After that, just above the RESOURCES section of the Toolbox, you'll see a "New Resource" button. First, create a Variable that uses the Data Type of Record (Collection) to hold your list of Seances. Then, create another Variable to hold a single Seance.

Now, you're going to assign values to each Seance to create, and then add it to the collection. Afterwards, you'll use the Create Records action to actually create the records.

Your overall design should look like the following screenshot.

[image: Sample Flow to Create Multiple Records]

The `#Counter` variable is what I'm using as an example for how many records to create. The Decision decides to stop after a certain number of records are created. There's other ways to do this, but this one is fairly common if you need to create multiple records.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for taking the TIME to explain it so well! I mean, I feel stupid even just saying that, THANK YOU!